# Having difficulty with 'with' function and median

Tags: sql, sql-server, median, with-statement

This code below is supposed to output the median of the set. Could you please tell me where I have gone wrong?

This is the original question from hackerrank:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem

```
Declare @max_lat int; 
With List as
(
Select LAT_N,Row_number() over (order by LAT_N) as rnk
from Station)
set @max_lat= (select max(rnk) from List);
select LAT_N from List
where rnk= ( case 
                when @max_lat%2=0 then @max_lat/2
                when @max_lat%2=0 then (@max_lat/2)+1
                else (@max_lat+1)/2
                end);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Also please add a `CREATE TABLE` statement to define the `Station` table (at least including `LAT_N` column), `INSERT` statements to provide sample data, and the actual error message received.

Comment: Added the link of the actual question in order to check your answers

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it'd be better to post the content, if it's allowed by the terms of that site. Otherwise I have to create an account just to see the question (and so does anyone else who sees this StackOverflow question in the future)

Comment: Your two `CASE...WHEN` conditions are the same.

Comment: OK, I see that I can just cancel the login to hackerrank.com and thus see the content. However, the content does not have any sample values, so it's hard to tell whether my solution answers their question.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that this is for Microsoft SQL Server.

The problem looks like it is that the `WITH` clause applies only to the statement that it begins. Your original code has two statements. The `WITH` therefore applies only to the first one, and thus you cannot `select LAT_N from List` because the CTE `List` is only defined for the `set @max_lat=` statement.

To avoid this problem, use a second CTE rather than a "temp variable":

```
With List as
(
Select LAT_N,Row_number() over (order by LAT_N) as rnk
from #Station),
MaxLat as ( select max(rnk) as max_lat from List )
select LAT_N from List
    INNER JOIN MaxLat 
    ON List.rnk= case 
               when MaxLat.max_lat%2 = 0 then MaxLat.max_lat/2
-- I'm leaving this here because it was in the OP but I don't understand why 
-- there are two when conditions that are the same
               when MaxLat.max_lat%2 = 0 then (MaxLat.max_lat/2)+1
               else (MaxLat.max_lat+1)/2
           end;
```

Finally, if you're interested in a wide variety of ways to compute the median, look at [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median).

Comment: That makes sense ! thank you, but do you think I could use the same logic in a different way perhaps?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Or you could move `CASE` logic into final `SELECT` as originally setup, cross joining or cross/outer applying the two CTEs.

Comment: @Parfait You'd still have to use the `max(rnk)` snippet repeatedly, no?

Comment: `max(rnk) as max_rnk` would only exist in second CTE but its column used in final: `SELECT... WHERE  rnk = CASE WHEN second_cte.max_rnk ...`

Comment: @Parfait - thanks, that does make it better. Edited answer again.